# RSiteCatalyst problem with adobe visitor id

Tags: r, adobe-analytics

Using RSiteCatalyst to fetch data from data warehouse I was able to get the Adobe Visitor ID elements The problem is value as been converted to numeric (scientific notation).

Is there a way to get the adobe visitor id as string?

Comment: you may change the options i.e. `options(scipen = 999)` to not convert to scientific notation

Comment: not exactly the same ... but I've just figured that the problem were not in the output of RsiteCatalyts method but in my string conversion. So your solution will work. However I've ended up using the 'scale::number_format' function